# Flutter Center align widget to specific coordinate

Tags: flutter, widget

Ive create a popup menu widget which takes two arguments :a button widget, and a menu widget . When the button is pressed the menu widget is passed to an OverlayEntry as the child which is then added to the Overlay.of(context)

I'd like the resulting display to be as such:

```
     O   (Button)
 ____|____
 | MENU  |
 |_______|
```

I can place the menu widget inside a Positioned Widget to move it freely around the Overlay, but I dont know how to get the correct coordinates. I can get the center of the Button by finding it's Renderbox, but I cant know the size, and therefore the correct position, of the Menu until after it's draw (as it can be any widget).

Is there some soft of layout option to tell a Widget of any size to vertically or horzontally align itself with a given coordinate?

Comment: use `Positioned > FractionalTranslation > YourMenu`

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, thank you!

Comment: well, personally I would use better approach as it does not guarantee your menu is completely visible for all cases - check `tooltip.dart` for more info

Comment: the key is a custom `SingleChildLayoutDelegate`: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tooltip.dart#L418

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of a widget:

First give your Widget a key:

```
key: _key,
```

Then you can get the size(and position) like this:

```
_getSize() {
    final RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final size = renderBox.size;
    final position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    final height = size.height; //same for width
 }
```

Comment: I already know how to get the renderbox, as i mentioned in my question... Im asking if there is some layoutoption to center a widget of "adaptive" width like a container on a specific coordinate

Comment: @ClaudeHasler Why can't you calculate the center of the widget using size and position and then align the center to your coordinate? Would be alot easier to help with some code and pictures.